# Getting image dimensions with Carrierwave: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick

I am trying to make different versions of image depending on uploaded image dimensions and I don't understand why is my code not saving width and height values. I am using Carrierwave. This is my code:

```
class HeadUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  #Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :image_dimensions
    width = @geometry.width
    height = @geometry.height


    if width < height
      process :resize_to_limit => [30, 60]
    else
      process :resize_to_limit => [60, 30]
    end
  end

  def image_dimensions
    manipulate! do |img|
      @geometry = { width: img.columns, height: img.rows }
    end
  end

end
```

For the line `width = @geometry.width` I receive the following error: `undefined method 'width' for nil:NilClass`

What do you think could be a problem?

Comment: `@geometry.width` is incorrect appeal to property, it should be `@geometry[:width]`, Also process probably not some synchronous operation, so you can't immediately get the result of it.

Comment: @zishe, thank you for suggestion. Now I receive this error: `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Try using `@@geometry` but i think it's impossible in a manner you are doing that.

Comment: @zishe, also not working. Why do you think it's impossible? What could be different possible approach?